# Why is Invoke task reexecuted on code change?

Tags: django, docker, invoke

I have defined [Invoke](https://www.pyinvoke.org) task that runs foo function and then starts my Django app. Whenever I change the code, the whole task is reexecuted. I don't understand why reload mechanism triggers the task. I want foo function to be called only on docker-compose up. Can somebody explain?

Setup:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    entrypoint: ["invoke", "my_task"]
    volumes:
      - .:/code
```

tasks.py:

```
from invoke import task
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")
django.setup()

@task
def my_task(context):
    foo()
    management.call_command("runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000")
```

Comment: If you run this command, does the Python process stay running, or does it exit immediately?  If the main container process exits, the container will exit too, and then `docker-compose up` will notice it's not running and try to recreate it.